# TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, types, floating-point

Can't post image, so: `a[i]={(-1)^(i+1)*sin(x)*ln(x)}/{i^2*(i+1)!}`

The task:
Need to find a1,a2,...,an.
n is natural and it's given.

That's the way I tried to do this:

```
import math
a=[]
k=0
p=0
def factorial(n):
   f=1
   for i in range(1,n+1):
     f=f*i
   return f

def narys(n):
    x=input('input x: ') #x isn't given by task rules, so i think that is error else.
    float(x)
    k=(math.pow(-1,n+1)*math.sin(x)*math.log10(n*x))/(n*n*factorial(n+1))
    a.append=k

n=int(input('input n: '))
narys(n)
for i in a:
   print(a[p])
   p=p+1
```

Answer (score 7):

Seems like you're using Python 3.x version. The result of an `input` call is a **string** taken from keyboard, which you pass to a `math.sin(...)` function. `float(x)` converts `x` to `float` but does not store the converted value anywhere, so change:

```
float(x)
```

to:

```
x = float(x)
```

to get right behaviour of your code.